# How to to make object property typed to be a string from another property's array of strings in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Good

```
{
  values: ['John', 'Steven', 'Sarah'],
  oneOfValue: 'Sarah',
}
```

Bad

```
{
  values: ['John', 'Steven', 'Sarah'],
  oneOfValue: 'Joe',
}
```

I've been messing around with generics and stuff but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the string elements of `values` to be dynamic, then you can't represent such a type in TypeScript as a concrete non-generic type.  Instead, you will need a generic type similar to the following:

```
type Acceptable<K extends string> = { values: K[], oneOfValue: K };
```

And then you would want to infer `K` from the value you write.  Unfortunately, this doesn't quite get you there:

```
const inferAcceptable = <K extends string>(a: Acceptable<K>) => a;

inferAcceptable({
  values: ['John', 'Steven', 'Sarah'],
  oneOfValue: 'Joe',
}); // no error! K inferred as "John" | "Steven" | "Sarah" | "Joe"
```

That's because the generic `K` in the `Acceptable<K>` will be inferred both from the `values` property, *and* from the `oneOfValue` property.  You end up with the union of `"John" | "Steven" | "Sarah"` *and* `"Joe"`, which is often what people want the compiler to do, but fails to catch this.

---

What you'd really like is some way to tell the `inferAcceptable()` function to infer the type parameter `K` from the `values` property and *not* to infer it from `oneOfValue`.  This idea is called "noninferential type parameter usage" and there's it's an open feature request (see [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829)).  There's no "official" way to do this, but that GitHub issue gives a bunch of techniques and workarounds that work in various situations.

[One such technique](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731) is to take any type parameter `T` you don't want to be used for inference and [intersect](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) it with the [empty object type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) like `(T & {})`.  So let's try that here:

```
const inferAcceptable = <K extends string>(v: { values: K[], oneOfValue: K & {} }) => v;
```

Does it work?

```
const good = inferAcceptable({
  values: ['John', 'Steven', 'Sarah'],
  oneOfValue: 'Sarah',
}); // okay

const bad = inferAcceptable({
  values: ['John', 'Steven', 'Sarah'],
  oneOfValue: 'Joe', // error!
  //~~~~~~~~ <-- "Joe" is not ("John" & {}) | ("Steven" & {}) | ("Sarah" & {})
});
```

Yes; `good` is accepted, and `bad` is rejected.  The error message in `bad` carries around those pesky intersections, though.

[Another technique](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546) uses deferred [conditional types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to prevent inference:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];

const inferAcceptable = <K extends string>(v: { values: K[], oneOfValue: NoInfer<K> }) => v;

const good = inferAcceptable({
  values: ['John', 'Steven', 'Sarah'],
  oneOfValue: 'Sarah',
}); // okay

const bad = inferAcceptable({
  values: ['John', 'Steven', 'Sarah'],
  oneOfValue: 'Joe', // error!
  //~~~~~~~~ <-- "Joe" is not "John" | "Steven" | "Sarah"
});
```

That also works, and the error message is the one you'd expect.

---

Okay, hope one of those solutions works for you.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQMZJlMBDARgGxgHgGk4YAPMGAOwBMBnOWsAJwEtKBzAPjgF44BvOADcMOAK4xaALjiEA2gF0ANHAD2lGAHkAZgDVREmcQC+AblCgk6xnDbaYTZKnTY8AOVWxecIiXJU6BmY2LgAKDBknNExcAkJOAEpebgxzEDhQOwcol1iPWFD+UDhhA0kZOQByAClVAAtKSpVKgGUKISomuFaMJgw6yuVitQ0dfXEYGRrVGCbQYwTTOAB6ZbhKVRImJlUmAEJZW0p7bZhqOAx6ACJahqu4AB84K7aYDsp7p5fe-s-n2pgVwsIFWcEgXg8AEljg58AAVbh8OFwABkAmMoHB8ChMKY8MRcDkcIURL8FBo9AwlAgcAA-HAAAxwGQaDpMBRpSzWMBHE45GJ4by+MjkwKMVgcTihIQyQQiCbSWSKFTqLR6MoyHEnIjcBbJYSckBWSg2diqVTnPhZRwoaKuGCFYbyiSKqq3RrNV7vLo9PoDIbpEZq8aGbotH4DJTzRYrNaqADWGAgwONNiwGEtvOyttyeEdged5UJ0waPq9nU9EcGUcDqrGGu6AK6oIcO32w1WAD9uz3uz4ALT9-4ze4segbHk3eofR7Pcszr7hv1AkALQ1AA)